# Dispatch the highest priority in WPF

Tags: wpf

Hi guys I would like to know what happens if I am in the middle of a task thats priority is Render and I create another task with priority send. Will Dispatcher will till its done with its tasks of priority render and then my task of highest priority which is send will be executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will Dispatcher will till its done with its tasks of priority render and then my task of highest priority which is send will be executed?

Yes.  The priority is only used when the `Dispatcher` starts each task.  It will not stop an operation already in process.